# Why referenced data is not available while it is still referenced?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-trigger

I have next relations (I left only related fields):

```
CREATE TABLE "operations" (
  "id" serial NOT NULL,
  "opdate" timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE "prows" (
  "id" serial NOT NULL,
  "operation_id" integer NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE "prows" ADD CONSTRAINT "prows_fk_operation_id" FOREIGN KEY ("operation_id")
  REFERENCES "operations" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

CREATE TRIGGER "prow_bd_changesaldo" before delete
  ON "prows" FOR EACH row EXECUTE PROCEDURE make_prow()
;

CREATE FUNCTION "make_prow" ()
 RETURNS TRIGGER
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $$
    DECLARE _count INT;
     BEGIN

    SELECT count(*) /* OP.OpDate */
      FROM Operations OP
      WHERE OP.ID = OLD.Operation_ID
      INTO _count;

    RAISE NOTICE 'COUNT: %', _count;

    ...

    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN RETURN OLD; ELSE RETURN NULL; END IF;/**/
    END;/**/
$$
```

I got that `count` is zero:

```
delete from operations ;
NOTICE:  COUNT: 0
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function make_prow() line 1 at RAISE
SQL statement "DELETE FROM ONLY "public"."prows" WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "operation_id""
...
```

So related row still exists while referenced row is gone. It seems very inconsistent to me and breaks integrity.

Is there any ways to get `Operations.OpDate` value from `make_prow` trigger?

Comment: The standard [specifies an even more harsh ordering](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-COMPATIBILITY): *SQL specifies that `BEFORE DELETE` triggers on cascaded deletes fire **after** the cascaded `DELETE` completes. The PostgreSQL behavior is for `BEFORE DELETE` to always fire before the delete action, even a cascading one.* -- But in either of these cases, the original `DELETE` operation are completed when the cascaded `DELETE` fires (and `BEFORE DELETE` fires just before the cascaded `DELETE` fires in PostgreSQL).

Comment: So in short: there is no such way. You need to create a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on `operations`.

Comment: The `CASCADE` deletion is still a delation, but current behavior seems cascade delation is implemented as `AFTER DELETE` trigger. But I expect `CASCADE` deletion should be implemented as `BEFORE DELETE` trigger with lowest priority

Comment: No, the trigger fires *before* the deletion of rows from `prows`, but *after* the deletion of rows from `operations` if that's what initiated it in the first place. You need a trigger on `operations` if you want to catch the whole operation before it happens.

Answer (score 1):

It is not surprising that the `DELETE` cascades to `prows` only after the rows in `operations` have been deleted.

To solve the problem, you can change `ON DELETE CASCADE` to `ON DELETE NO ACTION` and define a `BEFORE` trigger on `operations` that deletes the dependent rows in `prows` *before* the row in `operations` is deleted. That way the trigger on `prows` will be called before the row in `operations` is gone.

Comment: hm (( I expect to hear other solutions, Because I have this one =) But +1 and I will accept yours if this will be one answer